# How to use inline editing in angular Js without any buttons in the rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inline-editing

I have below table,

```
<div class="md-dialog-main">
                        <table class="me-hours-table">
                            <thead>
                                <th>Product Type</th>
                                <th>Product Name</th>
                                <th>
                                    <select>
                                        <option  style="background-color:'#FF0000'">weight</option>
                                        <option  style="background-color:'#FF0000'">size</option>
                                    </select>
                                </th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Qty</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="data in variants">
                                    <td>{{data.type}}</td>
                                    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{data.size}}</td>
                                    <td>{{data.price}}</td>
                                    <td>{{data.qty}}</td>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

The controlling part which take the data is as below,

```
 $scope.idDetails = function(product){
        var ids={
            mainId : product.mainId,
            childId : product.childId
            };
            console.log(ids.childId);
             commerceService.getVariants(ids.childId).
                    success(function(data) {
                     toastr.success('Successfully saved', 'Awsome!', {
                         closeButton: true
                     });
                    $scope.variants=[{
                        type: "cloth",
                        name: data[0].name,
                        size: "10",
                        price: data[0].price,
                        qty: "1"
                    }];
                    console.log($scope.variants.name);
                    }).error(function(err) {
                        toastr.error('Saving detals was not Successful', 'Warning', {
                            closeButton: true
                        });
                    });
        }
```

Everything works fine, but I want to use a Angular Js inline editor to edit the rows in the table. First the user can see the data which I get from the controller, then the user should be able to edit the rows. I have searched through the internet but I found inline editing tables which use button to edit and save. I don't want any buttons in my table rows. I want to bind data with the model. So that at the end I can take the data from the table via the model. Please help

Comment: There's an attribute called editable in html add it to your table data and set it to true like this  contenteditable="true"

Comment: and link those data with your controller with help of ng-model

Answer (score 1):

After searching in many areas I found an inline edit that do not need any button to edit. The code is as below,

```
<div class="md-dialog-main">
                        <table class="me-hours-table">
                            <thead>
                                <th>Product Type</th>
                                <th>Product Name</th>
                                <th>
                                    <select ng-model="selection">
                                        <option value="weight">weight</option>
                                        <option value="size">size</option>
                                    </select>
                                </th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Qty</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                <tr ng-repeat="data in variants">
                                    <td
                                       inline-edit="data.sku"
                                       inline-edit-callback="skuUpdateHandler(newValue)"
                                       inline-edit-btn-edit=""
                                       inline-edit-on-blur="save"
                                       inline-edit-on-click></td>
                                    <td
                                       ng-model="data.name">{{data.name}}</td>
                                    <td
                                       inline-edit="data.sizeOrweight"
                                       inline-edit-callback="sizeUpdateHandler(newValue)"
                                       inline-edit-btn-edit=""
                                       inline-edit-on-blur="save"
                                       inline-edit-on-click></td>
                                    <td
                                       inline-edit="data.price"
                                       inline-edit-callback="priceUpdateHandler(newValue)"
                                       inline-edit-btn-edit=""
                                       inline-edit-on-blur="save"
                                       inline-edit-on-click></td>
                                    <td
                                       inline-edit="data.qty"
                                       inline-edit-btn-edit=""
                                       inline-edit-on-blur="save"
                                       inline-edit-on-click></td>
                                </tr>
                                    <td 
                                       inline-edit-callback="qtyUpdateHandler(newValue)"
                                       inline-edit-btn-edit=""
                                       inline-edit-on-blur="save"
                                       inline-edit-on-click></td>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

The controller is as below,

```
$scope.skuUpdateHandler = function(newValue) {
  console.log(newValue);
};
$scope.sizeUpdateHandler = function(newValue) {
  console.log(newValue);
};
$scope.priceUpdateHandler = function(newValue) {
  console.log(newValue);
};
```

Please install ng-inline-edit to use this method. Click
https://github.com/tameraydin/ng-inline-edit to install ng-inline-edit